# RegExp.prototype.test returning mixed results

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a function which produces the following Regex for detecting Emojies which have been pasted into my applications text editor:

```
var regex = /:[smile|laughing|blush|relaxed|smirk|heart_eyes|flushed|satisfied|grin|wink|stuck_out_tongue|sleeping|worried|fearful|frowning|confused|disappointed|cry|sob|rage|sunglasses|innocent|yum|facepalm|heart|broken_heart|exclamation|question|zzz|+1|thumbsdown|woman|man|kiss|clap|sunny|umbrella|snowman|gift|dollar|airplane|rocket|boat|steam_locomotive|four_leaf_clover|bell|bulb|computer|hammer|phone|microphone|fork_and_knife|pizza|wine_glass|beer|cocktail|checkered_flag|sos|no_entry|white_check_mark]+:/gi
```

Provided with the same regex and the same input `RegExp.prototype.test` produces varying results in the browser.

**Example**

```
var regex = /:[smile|laughing|blush|relaxed|smirk|heart_eyes|flushed|satisfied|grin|wink|stuck_out_tongue|sleeping|worried|fearful|frowning|confused|disappointed|cry|sob|rage|sunglasses|innocent|yum|facepalm|heart|broken_heart|exclamation|question|zzz|+1|thumbsdown|woman|man|kiss|clap|sunny|umbrella|snowman|gift|dollar|airplane|rocket|boat|steam_locomotive|four_leaf_clover|bell|bulb|computer|hammer|phone|microphone|fork_and_knife|pizza|wine_glass|beer|cocktail|checkered_flag|sos|no_entry|white_check_mark]+:/gi
var match = ':ph:'
regex.test(match)
>>>true
regex.test(match)
>>>false
regex.test(match)
>>>true
regex.test(match)
>>>false
regex.test(match)
>>>true
regex.test(match)
>>>false
regex.test(match)
>>>true
```

**Screen Shot**

[image]

I read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) on this method and from everything I can tell this should be a pure function. Why is it returning different values provided with the same input?

Comment: Replace `[...]+` with `(...)`

Comment: JS Interpreter throws the following error when I do that: " Invalid regular expression: ... Nothing to repeat"

Comment: That is because your pattern contains an unescaped `+`. Escape it, too. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/iD3nH8/1). And when using `RegExp#test()` you should not use `/g`.

Comment: @Amit Even though I would agree with you that you found a dup, I would say that OP have two problems and your dup is only answering the later.

Comment: @dev-null  - the question is about varying results from the `test` function. That's a 100% dupe. The fact that there are other issues is irrelevant.

Comment: Ok, @chopperdrawlion4, if you have another issue please ask another question. This really is more about how your are using a regex than what issue there is with the pattern itself.